# What is the size of largest cliques in binomial random graph $G(n,p)$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-graphs

Binomial random graph $G(n,p)$ is an $n$-vertex graph such that each of the $\binom{n}{2}$ pairs is included as an edge independently with probability $p$.

I am wondering with high probability (the probability of an event tends to 1 as $n$ tends to infinity), what is the size of the largest clique in $G(n,p)$? (Here $p$ might be a function of $n$, i.e., $p(n)$.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $\omega_n$ denote the clique number of $G(n,p)$. For a constant $p$ [Grimmett & McDiarmid](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/on-colouring-random-graphs/38719DFD65620CD94A379293A3E50B7F) showed that
$$
\omega_n= -\frac{2}{\ln p}\ln n+o_{a.s.}(\ln n).
$$

Comment: Yes. What happens to $p=n^{-c}$, say?

Comment: @Connor When $p = n^{-c}$, the expected clique number is constant, and for fixed $k$ the threshold for $k$-cliques is $p = n^{-k/\binom k2} = n^{-2/(k-1)}$.